# Angular Reactive Forms validation not triggered after setErrors on child element

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

We have an Angular application which uses the backend for the validation.
The validation is made on the formGroups to handle cross validation between the elements.
We have async validator and when the validation result arrives we add the errors to the formControls in the formGroup aswell to mark them as invalid.

Now we encounter some strange behavior. After we call the setErros on the formControls the validation of the formGroup is no longer triggered with an input. If we have a formGroup with three formControls only changes to one of the three controls triggers the validation. Sometimes the formGroup stays invalid even if the values are valid.

I made an Stackblitz to show this behavior: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apifv7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

The validation in the example checks if the values in all 3 inputs are the same.

Does anyone know this problem or a solution?